# invalid content length or chunk length in the request

Tags: powershell

> "Bad Request Bad Request - Invalid Content Length HTTP Error 400.
> There is an invalid content length or chunk length in the request. At
> D:\a\1\s.......\ReleaseNotewithUpload.ps1:88 char:17 + … $response =
> Invoke-RestMethod $uploadURLObject.uploadUrl -Method 'PUT … +

Powershell line:

```
$uploadURLObject = GET-UPLOADLINK -clientId $clientId -clientSecret $clientSecret -nameofFile $nameWithoutExtension
    $tokenObject = GET-TOKEN -clientId $clientId -clientSecret $clientSecret
    $uploadHeaders = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $uploadHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/zip")
    $uploadHeaders.Add("Content-Range", "bytes " + 0 +"-" + ($fileSize-1) + "/" + $fileSize)    
    #$uploadHeaders.Add("Content-Length", $fileSize)
    $uploadHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+ $tokenObject.access_token)    
   # $uploadBody = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file)    
    $uploadBody = Get-Content -LiteralPath $file
    write-host "***UploadBody****"
    write-host $uploadBody
    write-host "***UploadHeader****"
    write-host $uploadHeaders
    foreach ($key in $uploadHeaders.Keys) 
    { 
    Write-Host "Key: $key    Value: $($uploadHeaders[$key])" 
    }
    write-host "*******"
    #$response = Invoke-RestMethod $uploadURLObject.uploadUrl -Method 'PUT' -Headers $uploadHeaders -Body $uploadBody -SkipHeaderValidation
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod $uploadURLObject.uploadUrl -Method 'PUT' -Headers $uploadHeaders -Infile $file
    $response | ConvertTo-Json    
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod $uploadURLObject.uploadUrl -Method 'PUT' -Headers $uploadHeaders -Infile $file -SkipHeaderValidation
```

UploadHeaders on printing i get:

```
Key: Content-Type    Value: application/zip
Key: Content-Range    Value: bytes 0-66704/66705
Key: Content-Length    Value: 66705
Key: Authorization    Value: Bearer rzoQ6Ls7YoaQGls8MBlPVScBPA...dfd
```

This is my second question with a different error message. I am running powershell cmdlet to upload a zip folder in sharepoint. What Wrong Am I doing here?

Comment: What does this have to do with Git?

Comment: ok, error occured in my azure devops pipeline. you are right i can remove Git.

Comment: Not sure, but could you try adding `Transfer-Encoding = "chunked"` to the `$uploadHeaders` ?

Comment: one thing I just figured out if i remove my Content-Length part from header it works. if anyone can explain what content-length has to do with this error. Updating my question with full code